# Update with $push MongoDB using bash script

Tags: bash, mongodb, insert-update

I am using a bash script to update my mongoDB. Here is the code I use:

```
mongo 127.0.0.1/foo --eval 'db.coll.update({"Name1": '"$arg1"', "Name2": '"$arg2"'}, {$push: {"Name3": '"$arg3"'}}, {upsert: true});'
```

The code above should update if existing document which is matching Nam1 and Name2. The value to update is arg3 in field Name3. This value is pushed, which means a new value is appended to the existing list.

But I get the error code:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected number

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you actually using "$arg1" or is that just a placeholder? I've had issues with mongodb freaking out when I try to save something with a "$" in it.

Comment: actually $arg1 is ${args[1]}. I am able to insert a document containing a variable, that's why it should also be possible to use a variable with update.

Comment: What you are doing wrong depends on the values of `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg3` - show them. You could also use `set -x` to see how the command is expanded.